# Floating point conversion - One format to another

Tags: floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I a question about converting one floating point representation to another.
I have a float point given:

0 111111 000000010 with exponent bits = 6 and exponent bias = 31, fraction bits = 9

I am to convert this to a new format where exponent bits = 5 and exponent bias = 15, fraction bits = 10

So I found the bias as 11111 = 63 - 31 = 32. So adding that to 15 would be 47 for the second format. However, since we only have 5 bits to use for the exponent bias, the max number we can get is 31. So I can't represent that number with the bits I am given.

So how would I convert this?

Comment: Are these supposed to be IEEE 754-style binary floating-point formats, with all the usual bells and whistles (infinities, signed zeros, nans, gradual underflow, hidden fraction bit, etc?). If so, please can you add that information to the question? IEEE 754 is not the only source of floating-point formats in existence!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the number is not representable as a finite number in the second format. You should clamp to infinity by setting the exponent to the maximum value and the mantissa to zero.